# Adding a form to user profile?

Tags: forms, users, 7

I would like to add a form to the user account page, is there a specific way of doing this?

I guess this leads me to a large question: how can you embed forms in pages? I understanding using hook_menu & the drupal_get_form callback. But this creates a new page, what about adding forms to an already existing page.

I have a feeling the answer is here: https://api.drupal.org/comment/6679#comment-6679, but I can't seem to understand it. Anyone have any good suggestions or tutorials....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add user forms by creating a render array for [the Form API](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer!topics!forms_api_reference.html/7) and *print render($form)* in a custom template, but I would just use [the Webforms module](https://drupal.org/project/webform) and include all elements in a Panel or View.

Comment: Where is the "drupaly" place to put the code for the render array? In the template file itself or in a custom module and call it from there?

Comment: A custom module would be the way to go, but either would work.